# Tkinter search query in database: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: search, tkinter, nonetype

I'm unable to solve a problem with a search query in the database (sqlite3) in Tkinter. Parts of my code:

> ## front.py
>
> ```
>     # Entries
>     self.name_text = tk.StringVar()
>     self.entry_name = tk.Entry(self.parent, textvariable=self.name_text)
>     self.entry_name.grid(row=3, column=1)
>
>     self.color_text = tk.StringVar()
>     self.combobox2=ttk.Combobox(self.parent, textvariable=self.color_text)
>     self.combobox2["values"] = ('red','blue','white')
>     self.labelCombobox=ttk.Label(self.parent, textvariable=self.color_text)
>     self.combobox2.grid(row=4, column=1)
>     self.parent.bind('<Return>',lambda e:refresh())
>     
> def search_command(self):
>     self.listBox.delete(0,tk.END)
>     for row in backend.database.search(self.name_text.get(),self.color_text.get()):
>         self.listBox.insert(tk.END, row)
> ```
>
> ## backend.py class database:
>
> ```
> def search(name="",color=""):
>     try:
>         connect = sqlite3.connect("color.db")
>         cur = connect.cursor()
>         sql = "SELECT * FROM color WHERE name=? OR color=?"
>         values = (self, name_text.get(), color_text.get())
>         cur.execute(sql, values)
>         rows = cur.fetchall()            
>         name_text.set(rows[1])
>         color_text.set(rows[2])
>         entry_name.configure('disabled')
>         combobox2.configure('disabled')
>         connect.close()
>     except:
>         messagebox.showinfo('nothing found!')
> ```

I also tried to put a self in in an other version of backend.py. This gives the same error.

> ```
>  def search(self, name="",color=""):
>     try:
>         self.connect = sqlite3.connect("color.db")
>         self.cur = self.connect.cursor()
>         self.sql = "SELECT * FROM color WHERE name=? OR color=?"
>         self.values = (self, name_text.get(), color_text.get())
>         self.cur.execute(sql, values)
>         self.rows = self.cur.fetchall()            
>         self.name_text.set(rows[1])
>         self.color_text.set(rows[2])
>         self.entry_name.configure('disabled')
>         self.combobox2.configure('disabled')
>         self.connect.close()
>     except:
>         messagebox.showinfo('nothing!')
> ```

Please help solve the error:

> for row in backend.database.search(self.name_text.get(),self.color_text.get()):
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: That error is telling you the search is returning `None`. Your code needs to handle that case.  Also, why do you think you need to add `self` as one of the values to be queried over?

Comment: I know that it means it is returning None (no rows). But do not know how to rewrite the code. The self didn't work.

Comment: You're using the result from the `search` method but you don't seem to be returning values from the `search` method. Is the code you posted the complete code for that function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues on the `backend.database.search()` function:

- `name_text` and `color_text` are undefined
- passed arguments `name` and `color` should be used in `values` instead
- it does not return any result (*this is the cause of the error*)

Below is a modified `search()` function:

```py
    def search(name="", color=""):
        rows = ()  # assume no result in case of exception
        try:
            connect = sqlite3.connect("color.db")
            cur = connect.cursor()
            sql = "SELECT * FROM color WHERE name=? OR color=?"
            values = (name, color) # use arguments name and color instead
            cur.execute(sql, values)
            rows = cur.fetchall()
            connect.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e) # better to see what is wrong
            messagebox.showinfo('nothing found!')
        return rows  # return result
```

Comment: Super, your changes are working. I couldn't have figured it out myself. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` means that your query is returning no rows.

That is at least partly because of this code:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM color WHERE name=? OR color=?"
values = (self, name_text.get(), color_text.get())
cur.execute(sql, values)
```

This caused `self` to be used for the `name` parameter, and the result of `name_text.get()` will be associated with the `color` attribute. The result of `color_text.get()` is ignored.

You need to remove `self` - your sql uses two parameters so you need to send it two parameters.

The other problem appears to be that you're iterating over the results of `search`, but `search` doesn't return anything. You need to add a `return` statement to the `search` function.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Unfortunately it didn't work. The same error appeared.  "for row in backend.database.search(self.name_text.get(),self.color_text.get()):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"

Comment: Well, that means that the query returned no information. Have you verified that `name_text.get()` and `color_text.get()` are returning what you think they should return? Are you certain that those values match data in the database?

Comment: Yes, because there is also a working insert and delete command. In het view command the rows show up and i can select them with the cursor and delete them. Only the search command does not work.

Comment: @green If you are using the correct values for the select and the database has the values,  the query _will_ return values. The only logical conclusion is that the query parameters are not what you're assuming they are. The first step is to verify they are what you think they are.